# Rollup gives error when using Big.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rollupjs

I'm currently working on a library (written in TypeScript) for Angular 4.x. The necessary JavaScript bundles are created with [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). It all worked fine until I added the [big.js library](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) and the corresponding typings (`@types/big.js`).

I import it like this:

```
import * as Big from 'big.js';
import BigJS = BigJsLibrary.BigJS;
```

And use it like this:

```
// instantiating
let bigValue = Big(value);

// example of parameter usage
private someFunction(value: BigJS) { /* some code */ }
```

When running Rollup, I now receive the following error: `Error: Cannot call a namespace ('Big')`. My first thought was to add `big.js` to the list of externals for Rollup (`external: [ 'big.js' ]`). This does not solve the problem however.

I could see that the BigJS library has no (default) exports, so I tried using the  [commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) and [nodeResolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) Rollup plugins like this:

```
  plugins: [
      nodeResolve({
          jsnext: true,
          main: true
      }),
      commonjs({})
  ]
```

I have a feeling that I'm overseeing something obvious. I'd be thankful if someone could point out the mistake that I'm making here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an imported *namespace* (the `* as Big` part) is a TypeScript idiom which is incompatible with ES modules. Try doing this instead:

```js
import Big from 'big.js';
```

You'll still need the node-resolve and commonjs plugins, since Big.js is a CommonJS module.

Comment: Ah, forgot that it was a TypeScript construct. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!